# How to make Virtual Private SQL server renting service with a single server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, virtualization, vps

May i know is there any software supporting this task ?
or probably how people providing SQL server renting service ?
implementing "virtual" and "private" SQL server for developer 
which allow them to remote access their server...

Answer (score 0):

You can install multiple instance of sql server on the same machine.  But this venture isn't likely to work well, as it doesn't take much for a single sql server instance to peg a machine on any of cpu, ram, or disk io.

Comment: if and only if i install multiple instance, will it allowed customer to remote control without bother other server ??

Comment: @Spencer No, they won't be allowed to RDP in.  They will be able to connect via Management Studio and do anything you want from there.  If you want to allow them to RDP, you should look at VMWare.  Your licensing costs are _much_ better going the instance route.

Comment: Thx for reply, dude... if i want them to access via management studio, how could i make it up and act like shared hosting but not hosting website is hosting sql server only... this action formally what it called that i can found inside sql books ? Thx for reply =D